# Best Practice: res folders - Xdpi vs swXXXdp

Tags: android

I've been developing for about 5 years and have always used 'dpi' folders in my res directory (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc) with 'sw' folders for tablets (sw600dp, sw720dp, etc).

I've noticed in Android Studio that, starting with the Nexus 6, google lists its newer devices in sw buckets rather than in dpi buckets.

I know we can still use dpi folders but **SHOULD** we?  Or should we be transitioning to sw folders for all device sizes?

Or does it not matter?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> google lists its newer devices in sw buckets rather than in dpi buckets.

First, those are independent concepts:

- `sw` is "smallest width" and refers to size
- `dpi` is "dots per inch" and refers to screen density

Also, there is no occurrence of "sw" in that screenshot that I can see. So, I do not know what is worrying you.

One guess is that you are looking at values like `420dpi` and `xhdpi` and thinking that they are different concepts. They are both densities. The Android Studio UI is listing finer-grained density buckets than we use for our resources. `xhdpi` is 320dpi, for example.

Another guess is that you are looking at values like `420dpi` and thinking that means `-sw420dp`, which is not the case.

> I know we can still use dpi folders but SHOULD we?

For bitmaps, yes. For anything else, no.

> Or should we be transitioning to sw folders for all device sizes?

Using size-based folders — `-wNNNdp`, `-hNNNdp`, or `-swNNNdp` for varying values of `NNN` — may be necessary depending on your UI. If you need different layouts or margins or padding or something based on screen size, those folders are useful.

Comment: You're 100% right.  I was looking at the dpi values in terms of swNNNdp

Comment: @Psest328: Unfortunately, `dp` and `dpi` are suffixes that differ by just one letter but mean very different things.